# How to execute Below Program

Tags: apex

```
public class CreateAccount {

   public Account creatingAccount(String Name){

    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = Name;
    return acc;


  }

}
```

Comment: please take some time to review [ask] and try to narrow down your question to a specific problem with a clear description and the expected behavior of your code.

Comment: Try execute anonymous from developer console

Comment: From Developer console,  CreateAccount  c = new CreateAccount (); Account acct = c.creatingAccount('test');

Comment: Add in __any class__ or in __Execute anonymous from developer console__ Add code: `CreateAccount c = new CreateAccount();
Account acct = c.creatingAccount('Account Name');`
That's it;

Comment: Hey! I have inserted  through anonymous but not visible in the UI Page

Comment: Check the checkbox saying __Open log__ and if you have added any `System.debug('data to log')` then you will see here.

Answer (score 1):

That is not really a program but a class. You can execute this class from different places. There are a few things that may need to be modified. 
You probably want to insert the new account `acc`.

```
public class CreateAccount {

    public Account creatingAccount(String accName){
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = accName;
        insert acc;
        return acc; 
  }

}
```

On this code, you are inserting the account `acc`

If you want to execute this code this code, do the following:

Within Salesforce click on your name in the top right corner. 
Click on **Developer Console**.

click on **Ctrl+E** and a new window will pop up.

**Insert this:**

```
CreateAccount a = new CreateAccount();
Account acc = a.creatingAccount('AccName');
```

That should do it.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. All you need to do is to create a Custom Field of type Lookup-Relationship.  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=overview_of_custom_object_relationships.htm&type=0